# How can I learn more spells?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

After playing for a bit it is clear that some of the spells I picked are not that great. I'd like to learn some other spells to switch out my bad or redundant spells, but I haven't found out how to learn more spells outside of leveling up.

How do I learn more spells as a wizard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [pillars of eternity wiki](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Wizard_spell), wizards can learn new spells by leveling up or by reading looted enemy grimoires and paying a research cost.

The original source is a [forum post by Josh Sawyer](http://forums.obsidian.net/topic/65829-update-74-the-mob-rulers-wizards-and-druids-and-our-partnership-with-paradox/):

> Outside of combat, wizards can outfit their grimoires with any spells that they have learned. If they come across a spell in an enemy's grimoire, they can choose to learn that spell for the cost (in copper pieces) required to research it.

I have not yet encountered any enemy grimoires in game to test this.

Answer (score 7):

You can learn more spells outside of leveling up by looting Grimoires.

Once a Wizard acquires a new grimoire, simply place it in their inventory, and **Right Click** on the grimoire, as you would to see the stats on any other item. Any spells stored in the Grimoire which your Wizard does not know will have a small **+** icon on the top right corner. Clicking on this will give you the option of learning a new spell, at a cost of 100cp Per Level of the spell being learned.

[image: Grimoire]

The first such Grimoir that you're likely to find is on the eastern end of **Magran's Fork**, just south of Gilded Vale. You'll encounter a pair of Goldpact Paladins, accompanied by a wizard named Ludrana. They'll attack on sight, and after looting Ludrana's corpse, you'll have a new Grimoire to learn a few new spells from.

Alternately, if you're interested in learning a *specific* set of spells, and have gold to burn, you can hire a new Wizard adventurer at the Inn. Give this hireling all the spells you'd like your wizard to learn, and then steal his grimoire before kicking him out of the party.

Comment: so basically, if you were to remove these spells from a new Grimoir before you learned these spells, they would be lost, right?

Comment: @pootzko Yes, though the game will pop up a warning of this.